# WPF VB.NET でListBoxの一番最後の行のテキスト色を変える

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Visual Studio 2013 
VB.NET
WPF

ListBoxの中に何行か行が入っているんですが、
その一番したの行のテキストに色を付けたい場合、
どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

自己レスです。

リストに`Add`するときに、`ListBoxItem`にプロパティを設定すればできました。

```
Dim lbi As New ListBoxItem
lbi.Content = fileName
lbi.Foreground = Brushes.Red
ListBox1.Items.Add(lbi)
```

どなたかの参考になれば幸いです。

ありがとうございました。